# How to get variable from another class without instantiation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How would i pass a varible from another class without instanting the class? the reason i do not want to instantiate the class is because i would have to pass self.master which would mess up the classes window i am passing the variable to.

```
class MainPageGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Jans Corp")
        self.master.configure(background='lightgrey')
        self.master.geometry("1200x800")

        listbox = tk.Listbox(self.master,width=150, height=35) # varibable i would like to use in the other class
        listbox.place(x=150, y = 130)
```

Class i would like to pass the variable in:

```
class NewEmployee:
    def __init__(self, master): #Creating basic GUI to add employees

        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Jans Corp")
        self.master.configure(background="lightgrey")
        self.master.geometry("300x500")

        aa = MainPageGUI(self.master) ## my attempt at it, its wrong as the class get

        self.listbox = self.aa.listbox
```

Comment: You want to pass `self.master` without instantiating `self`, that would be black magic...

Comment: You don't pass variables; you pass *values*. What is the value from an instance of `MainPageGUI` that you need to create an instance of `NewEmployee`?

Comment: Your question is basically *"I want to make chicken filets without purchasing any chicken"*. See how that doesn't make any sense? You can't use only a part of the `MainPageGUI` class. You either use the whole thing, or nothing. I don't know why you think you want to do that, but we might be able to help you figure out a solution if you describe what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: You seem to be confused about variables and attributes of instances. If you *did* run the code you posted, then you would first need to change it to `self.aa = MainPageGUI(self.master)`, but then `self.aa.listbox` would give an attribute error, but you could fix *that* with `self.listbox = tkListbox(...` in `MainPageGUI`.

Comment: by pass i meant use, sorry for the confusion. @chepner

Comment: The error i am recieving right now is that the `listbox` in `MainPageGUI` is not being identified, when i try to add data to the listbox the error says `New Employee  has no attribute Listbox` which is why i am trying to use it in `NewEmployee` and am naming it `listbox` to make sure the listbox can be read.

Comment: @Aran-Fey i am getting a confusing error which is why i am trying to use this attempt. i am at a loss as to why `MainPageGUI` does not read `self.listbox`. The error is something i cannot get past and its also something i dont understand.

Comment: I don't see why you are trying to create a separate class for the listbox. Just create the listbox in your main class. Even if you have a good reason your class that creates the list box does not need any of the other code above it.

Comment: _" i am at a loss as to why MainPageGUI does not read self.listbox"_ - it's because you never create `self.listbox`. You create a local variable named `listbox`, but that's not the same thing. Also, within `NewEmployee` you don't create any listboxes at all.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have made and tested `self.listbox` in `MainPageGUI` before i asked on stackoverflow, that code gave me the error i gave before: `NewEmployee has no attribute listbox` which is why i am now trying a different method.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I am only showing partial code as the rest was not relevant, although if you would like to see the whole code i can post the git link: https://github.com/Sharjeel50/Database-System/blob/master/New%20Project1.py

Comment: The problem is simple: for you to be able to use `self.listbox` you must create `self.listbox`. This isn't unique to tkinter, it's just how python works.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have... and i received the error `NewEmployee has no attribute listbox` which is why im confused

Comment: A really simple debugging tip: add print statements where you create the variable, and print statements where you use the variable, and then see which one comes first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general terms, the answer to "How to get variable from another class without instantiation?" is "you can't".

Your code example doesn't provide enough information to give a more concrete example. We don't know, for example, how, when, or where you create the instance of `MainPageGUI`, or how, when, and where you create an instance of `NewEmployee`.

I'm going to assume you've already created an instance of `MainPageGUI` before creating a `NewEmployee`.

In your case, you're trying to access something in `MainPageGUI` from another class. You don't want to create *another* `MainPageGUI`. Instead, what you need is a reference to the original `MainPageGUI`. Since that class must be instantiated somewhere, you simply need to pass that instance down when creating a new `NewEmployee`.

That means that you need to define `NewEmployee` something like this:

```
class NewEmployee:
    def __init__(self, master, main_gui): 

        self.main_gui = main_gui
        ...
```

Then, anywhere in `NewEmployee` where you need to reference the listbox, you would use `self.main_gui.listbox`.

Of course, this also requires that `MainGUI` actually defines `self.listbox`. Right now your code does `listbox = tk.Listbox(...)` when it needs to be `self.listbox = tk.Listbox(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although now im getting an error stating `MainPageGUI has no attribute 'listbox`. Is their any reason why this may occur?

Comment: @YouKnowMe: of course there's a reason. If it says it has no attribute `listbox`, then that's exactly what it means. You're either not creating `self.listbox`, or you're trying to use it before you create it.

Comment: The listbox ive defined shows on the mainpage, ive also used `self.` to show that it belongs to the class.

Comment: @YouKnowMe: python will not lie to you about this. If it says there's no attribute, you can be certain there's no attribute with that name. Again, add print statements where you create it and print statements where you try to use it. That will show if you're doing things in the wrong order.